# HybridAuth (any Version) Install Issue

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, hybridauth

**What I am trying to do:**

Install the files provided in the 2.2.2 release of HybridAuth. *(I have downloaded the 2.2.2 (incl. 2.3.0 and others) found here: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/releases)* and simply view the working samples.

**Issue I am Having:**

After following the setup instructions *(also mentioned below)* I navigate to each example. Hello World, Widget integration come up completely blank, Tiny Social Hub shows options but are blank upon selecting anything, Sign-in/Sign-up Users wants to connect to SQL, and Basic Facebook integration is blank after selection as well.

**Install Steps Completed:** (For each version)

1. Downloaded, Unzipped and Uploaded the Package
2. Navigated to the install.php *(www.website.com/hybridauth/install.php)*
3. Set the 'HybridAuth Endpoint URL' to :
   http://website.com/hybridauth/
4. Obtained a Consumer Key & Consumer Secret from Twitter.
   ([apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com))
5. I disabled all Adapter Status of all providers other than Twitter.
6. I entered my Key and Secret for Twitter
7. On the bottom of the page I clicked "Setup HybridAuth"
8. I then verified the submitted Data was wrote to the config.php
   correctly.
9. I deleted the install file.
10. Lastly, attempted again to view any of the examples provided with
    the package.

> **Note:** I have tried this with versions: **2.3.0** - **2.2.2** - **2.2.1** - **2.2.0** - **2.1.1**

**Server Check:**

After realizing that all of them can not be broken as so many people have used these packages. I also checked my hosting server.

I have the newest versions of PHP, cURL, SQL, have more than enough PHP memory... Nothing truly is out of the ordinary.

**Other:**

It would seem that every time the system is asked to visit a provider ('twitter', ect) it just sits there with a white screen as if its trying to tell me...well you know what I mean.

I have tried to edit, rewrite, and search the internet with no luck.

Comment: Anyone out there that could look at this?

Comment: anyone have the same issue?